# Neo4J / Is SKIP efficient when handling pagination?

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, neo4j, cypher

Using a relational database like MySQL, it is well known that the pattern `LIMIT x, y`  with a huge `x` can lead to bad performance in quickness and memory especially.

Some solutions to well handle this issue in MySQL are illustrated [here](http://www.xarg.org/2011/10/optimized-pagination-using-mysql/).

**Using Neo4j**, I wonder if the Cypher pattern: `SKIP X LIMIT Y`.. can lead to the same order of issues if `X` is huge, or if it is handled differently and in an optimized fashion by Neo4j so that I can use it without worrying about performance/memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can lead to similar problems. It is not optimized other than the query plan being cached and hopefully some of the nodes/rels being in the cache--it will need to skip all the way to the end of X each time.

Further, without range index lookups, it's difficult to workaround with the usual SQL way of doing:

```
WHERE val > lastOnPreviousPage
LIMIT Y
```

I'm hopeful they'll fix this pattern in an upcoming release, but for now it's a good idea to make your pages big and try to avoid skipping a lot of records.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I have about 10 000 elements that I want to paginate 20 per 20. How would you handle this? Making each page really bigger than 20 items?

Comment: 10k isn't the end of the world for handling it with SKIP, but it won't be super efficient.

Comment: Understood :)  I will handle this with `SKIP` for now. Just one last question: You wrote that it's difficult to workaround like in SQL. But I could involve an index that would work as the point of reference, avoiding to use `SKIP` and its drawbacks, exactly like the `lastOnPreviousPage`, couldn't it?

Comment: I think I understand: `WHERE val == lastOnPreviousPage` would use the index (while making no sense in this context), but in a kind of comparison like the operator `>`, it would need a way to build a range index.

Comment: If you have fairly static data, you could precalculate pages and keep a page property for an exact index lookup.

Comment: Also, if you have your nodes connected in order via relationships, you can pull them from the linked list. This is a bit more orchestration while removing/adding, though.

Comment: I don't think I'm figuring out what you've just wrote. What do you mean by "pull" in this case? Can you provide a little example?

Comment: If you order your items and connect them together with :NEXT relationships, you can get the last item on the page, and the next 20 of them for the next page. By pull I mean run a Cypher query like:
`MATCH (i:Item {id:{lastOnPage})-[:NEXT*..20]->(last)
RETURN collect(last) as pageOfItems`